# Eliminar un registros y los registros relacionados a esta, MySql

Tags: mysql

saben como puedo eliminar un registro y a la vez todos registros relacionados a esta , actualmente tengo tengo la tabla tb_artista en la cual quiero eliminar un registro de esa tabla con el id AR1, a la vez en tb_album quiero eliminar una tabla  con id AL1 que tiene el id AR1 como llave forarena, y a su vez quiero eliminar un registro de la tabla musica que tiene como llave foranea el id AL1, nose si me dejo explicar aqui esta mi script mysql:

```js
create database ProyectoMusica;
use ProyectoMusica;


create table tb_artista(
idartista varchar(200) primary key,
nombreartista varchar(90),
anonacimiento varchar(90),
descripcion1 text,
descripcion2 text,
fotoartista varchar(90)
);

insert into tb_artista values('AR1','Adam Gointer','18/02/1988','Nose','Nose','AdamGointer');
insert into tb_artista values('AR3','E Gointer','18/02/1988','Nose','Nose', 'EGointer');



create table tb_album(
idalbum varchar(200) primary key,
idartista varchar(200),
nombrealbum varchar(200),
tipo varchar(20),
fotoalbum varchar(100),
fechacreacion varchar(20),
FOREIGN KEY (idartista) REFERENCES tb_artista(idartista)
);

insert into tb_album values('AL1','AR1','Dulce Agonia','FREE','DulceAgonia', CURDATE());

create table tb_musica (
idmusica varchar(200) primary key,
idalbum varchar(200),
nombremusica varchar(90),
tamaño decimal(8,2),
FOREIGN KEY (idalbum) REFERENCES tb_album(idalbum)
);
```

Actualizo Intente de esta forma pero no me sale:

```js
 delete tal,tar,tm from  tb_artista as tar inner join  tb_album as tal
 on tar.idartista=tal.idartista inner join tb_musica as tm on tal.idalbum = tm.idalbum
 where tar.idartista = 'AR1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas establecer las relaciones de tus llaves foráneas con:

`ON DELETE CASCADE`

y también

`ON UPDATE CASCADE`

De modo que cuando elimines un registro padre, el registro hijo asociado se elimine también

Si apenas estas creando tu base de datos, tu tabla debería tener una declaración similar a esta

```
CONSTRAINT fk_album_artista FOREIGN KEY(idartista) 
REFERENCES tb_artista(idartista) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

**RECUERDA QUE DEPENDIENDO DE LO QUE NECESITES HACER, TIENES:**

> 1. On delete cascade: Que elimina el registro asociado a la llave primaria
> 2. On delete restrict: Impide llevar a cabo dicha acción
> 3. On delete SET NULL: Establece a `NULL` los valores asociados a la llave primaria que se esta eliminando
> 4. On delete no action: en MYsql poner `NO ACTION` tiene el mismo efecto que poner `RESTRICT` es decir impedir que dicha acción se lleve
>      a cabo

Comment: En que parte declaro eso, me puede ayudar porfavor, y otra parte osea cuando elimino el padre que es tb_artista voy a eliminar el hijo que es tb_album, lo que quiero saber que si tambien voy a eliminar el registro de tb_ musica que esta relacionado con el tb_album

Comment: Actualizo: Gracias amigo ahora cuando elimino un registro por su id de la tabla artista automaticamente elimino sus relaciones con las demas tablas

Comment: Gracias bro +1, me va ha ayudar para mi proyecto de mi universidad